# php cli no apache?

Tags: php, command-line

The way I understand PHP CLI is: it's no longer using a webserver ( which apache in most common setup)? Am I right about this? so if I run a php via CLI it will no longer call apache to trigger PHP, it instead calling the PHP directly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Yes that's correct PHP-CLI will not use apache, apache is a webserver to server web pages, but here we are running PHP directly in CLI so we don't need apache